# Windows 7 Startup Problems with Ethernet Driver

Tags: windows-7, networking, boot

Everytime I restart Windows 7, my Ethernet driver can't connect:

[image]

And I have to go into Device Manager -> Network Adapters and disable then enable the Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller to connect to the internet.

And now, lately everytime I start up, I've been getting this error:

[image]

Why do these happen when I start up Windows?

Answer (score 1):

A similar problem I had with the Release Candidate version of 7 was solved by rolling the ethernet driver back one version. The website listed a Win7 compatible driver, but when I had that installed it was not recognized; once I rolled it back, it worked fine.

(This problem has ceased in the current version of Win7 though, the newest drivers work fine.)

Comment: I'm using the latest version of Windows 7.